# Find maximum values on chart using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find on chart maximums like these:
[image]

This is my DataFrame.

```
dt_object       coordinate
01.01.2019 0:00     1.4601
01.01.2019 1:00     1.46051
01.01.2019 2:00     1.46092
01.01.2019 3:00     1.46133
01.01.2019 4:00     1.46173
01.01.2019 5:00     1.46214
01.01.2019 6:00     1.46254
01.01.2019 7:00     1.46294
01.01.2019 8:00     1.46334
01.01.2019 9:00     1.46374
```

The search algorithm is as follows:

0. Script runs from first row to last.
1. Script takes current row and looks at coordinate.
2. Script takes 10 previous rows and 10 next rows.
3. If current coordinate is largest value between 10 previous and 10 next values, so this is maximum.

I've implemented this task using iteration. But it works very slow. Is it possible to speed up the process of finding maximum values using the power of pandas?

```
df_work=df_work.assign(max=False)  # add new column 'max'. Default value is False
df_len = len (df_work)
for row in df_work.iterrows():
    index = row[0]
    value = row[1][1]
    if (index > 10) and index < (df_len - 10):
        # get previous and future values
        collect_neighbours = []
        for i in range (1, 10+1):
            prev_val = df_work['coordinate'][index - i]
            fut_val = df_work['coordinate'][index + i]
            collect_neighbours.append(prev_val)
            collect_neighbours.append (fut_val)
        max_in_neighbours = max(collect_neighbours)
        if value >= max_in_neighbours:
            print ('maximum is found!')
            df_work.at[index, 'max'] = True
```

Comment: [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) has a bunch of ways to do this, if you aren't glued to using your own method

Comment: @ALollz, I will try this method. But may be I can do it inside pandas?

Comment: There's no dedicated method for something like this. But it's really as simple as `find_peaks(df_work['coordinate'], other_args)` and then you can use the returned index as the `.iloc` indices to slice your DataFrame.

Comment: You could slice up the dataframe into chunks small enough so that there will only be one max, then find the max in each of them. e.g slice on `coordinate=0` then take the max in each of these slices.

Comment: @ALollz, find_peaks is looking for maximums. May be there is a function inside this library to find minimums (lows)?